# Indicate an "added entry to the index" in the main text

Tags: indexing, glossaries, highlighting

I'm writing a text with many index entries:

```
Variable $\Kappa$\index{Kappa@$\Kappa$} is used to ...
```

I'd like to see a hint in the main text, that an entry was added to the index. I tried using `\renewcommand`, but it didn't work:

```
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
%\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\index{#1}\textbf{GY}}
\renewcommand{\index}{\textbf{GY}\index}
\makeglossaries
```

Is there an easy way to show a hint in the main text, that an index entry was added?

Comment: The problem in using `\index` in the redefinition of `\index` is that it is self-referential in a way that can't break out of the loop.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with `glossaries`, so I'm not sure why you have added it to your example. (Indexing can be done via `glossaries`, but not via `\index`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to use glossaries, but perhaps this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\let\svindex\index
\def\index{\textbf{GY}\svindex}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Variable $\kappa$\index{kappa@$\kappa$} is used to ...
\end{document}
```

In this case, a copy of the original `\index` is stored in `\svindex`.  Then, the redefinition of `\index` calls upon the stored copy of the original, rather than calling upon itself in an endless loop.

I can get away without specifying the argument list to `\index`, because `\svindex` is the very last thing the redefinition does.  In this way, it will find its arguments waiting for it in the input stream, even though I haven't specified how those arguments should be structured.